# Exercise 2.2.12 in Topology and Groupoids

Tags: general-topology

The following is Exercise 2.2.12 is Ronald Brown’s *Topology and Groupoids*, which tries to characterize topological spaces using the relation “$A$ is contained in the interior of $B$”.

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $⊲$ a relation on subsets of $X$ such that
>
> 1. $∅ ⊲ ∅$ and $X ⊲ X$
> 2. $A ⊆ A'$, $A' ⊲ B'$, $B' ⊆ B$ imply $A ⊲ B$.
> 3. $A ⊲ B$ implies $A ⊆ B$.
> 4. $A ⊲ B$ and $A' ⊲ B'$ imply $A ∩ A' ⊲ B ∩ B'$.
> 5. $A_i ⊲ B_i$ for all $i ∈ I$ implies $⋃_{i ∈ I} A_i ⊲ ⋃_{i ∈ I} B_i$.
>
> For each $x ∈ X$, $A ⊆ X$ define $A$ to be a neighbourhood of $x$ if $\{ x \} ⊲ A$. Prove that these neighbourhoods define a topology on $X$ for which $A ⊲ B$ if and only if $A ⊆ \operatorname{Int}(B)$.

By a *topology* the book means a *neighbourhood topology* in the following sense:

> Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal{N}$ be a function assigning to each $x$ in $X$ a set $\mathcal{N}(x)$ of subsets of $X$.
> The elements of $\mathcal{N}(x)$ will be called neighbourhoods of $x$.
> The function $\mathcal{N}$ is a *neighbourhood topology* if it satisfies the following axioms for each $x$ in $X$:
>
> 0. The set $\mathcal{N}(x)$ is non-empty.
> 1. If $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, then $x ∈ N$.
> 2. If $N$ is a subset of $X$ containing a neighbourhood of $x$, then $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.
> 3. The intersection of any two neighbourhoods of $x$ is again a neighbourhood of $x$.
> 4. Any neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ contains a neighbourhood $M$ of $x$ such that $N$ is a neighbourhood of each point of $M$.

---

My attempts so far:

- It is not hard to see that properties 0–3 of a neighbourhood topology are satisfied, but I’m struggling to show property 4.
  Given a neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ we can consider the set
  $$
    M
    =
    \{
      y ∈ N
    \mid
      \{ y \} ⊲ N
    \}
  $$
  and this should a posteriori do the job.
  But I don’t see why $M$ should be a neighbourhood of $x$.
  I also tried to modify this approach by defining $N^{(0)} ≔ N$, $N^{(1)} ≔ M$, etc. and then considering $⋂_{n = 0}^∞ N^{(0)}$.
  But this doesn’t seem to work either.
- I also tried to solve the exercise the other way around:
  It follows from the properties of the relation $⊲$ that the set
  $$
    \mathcal{U} ≔ \{ A ⊆ X \mid A ⊲ A \}
  $$
  forms a topology in the usual sense on $X$ (i.e., a collection of “open subsets” satisfying certain conditions).
  Is is then not hard to see that $A ⊆ \operatorname{Int}(B)$ implies $A ⊲ B$, but I don’t see how the reverse implication is supposed to work.
- I suspect by now that the exercise may be missing some additional requirement on the relation $⊲$. There seems to be the more general notion of a *pretopological space* for which axiom 4 of a neighbourhood topology is not required. In such a space $X$, one can still define the *preinterior* of a subset $A$ of $X$ as
  $$
    \operatorname{PreInt}(A)
    =
    \{
      x ∈ X \mid \text{$A$ is a neighbourhood of $x$}
    \}.
  $$
  It seems to me that the relation $⊲$ given by $A ⊲ B$ iff $A ⊆ \operatorname{PreInt}(B)$ should satisfy all of the given conditions. But the resulting “topology” is just the original pretopology.

Comment: In 4. you mean $A' ⊲ B'$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I fixed it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: It seems to me that the following example shows axiom 4 of neighbourhood topology is not necessary satisfied, as you stated. Consider $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and suppose that $\emptyset\triangleleft Y$ and $Y\triangleleft X$, for all $Y\subseteq X$; moreover we require that $\{1\}\triangleleft \{1,2\}$. Now $\{1,2\}$ is a neighbourhood of $1$ but not of $2$, moreover it contains no other neighbourhood of $1$ so contradicts axiom 4. If I've made no mistake, then the properties $1-5$ for $\triangleleft$ are all verified.

Comment: I've checked what @WiktorVacca wrote and this is indeed correct. Even if we take neighbourhoods of each of the points $x\in \{1, 2, 3\}$ as our topology (the wording in the exercise is a bit confusing about this), we wouldn't obtain the property that $A◃B$ iff $A\subseteq\text{int}(B)$. Clearly this exercise needs to be corrected somehow.